# Threading Building Blocks using std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, tbb-flow-graph

i've just started to work with TBB. Have to say it looks very nice, however I ran into the following issue. Using a lambda with std::shared_ptr does not seem to work.

```
source_node<int>(g,[&](int& val) -> bool {val = 0; return true;},false);
source_node<std::shared_ptr<int>(g,[&](std::shared_ptr<int> val) -> bool {val = std::make_shared<int>(0);return true;},false);
```

with the following compile error:

```
error: C2665: 'std::shared_ptr<int>::shared_ptr' : none of the 5 overloads could convert all the argument types
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\memory(504): could be 'std::shared_ptr<int>::shared_ptr<main::<lambda_484cee4d4b0231890bebaeba94e0ddad>,bool>(std::nullptr_t,_Dx,_Alloc)'
with
[
    _Dx=main::<lambda_484cee4d4b0231890bebaeba94e0ddad>
]
```

basically the int has been replaced with std::shared_ptr.

Any ideas would be apreciated!

regards Auke

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Does fixing the syntax error (missing `>` after `std::shared_ptr<int>`) help?

Comment: My god, talking about a blind spot there, thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx Mike Seymour

```
source_node<std::shared_ptr<int>>(g,[&](std::shared_ptr<int> val) -> bool {val = std::make_shared<int>(0);return true;},false);
```